# Ubuntu 14.04 = fn+f2/f3 (backlight) keys not working

Tags: 14.04, kernel, brightness, fglrx, keys

With 14.04 LTS Ubuntu (64-bit), using any of the offered kernel solutions (including ones from the newer releases up to 3.19), f2/f3 brightness controls fail to register. As a matter of fact key presses in dmesg are reported as unknown keys, suggesting there is something funny with the way kernel interprets these key presses:

atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xab on isa0060/serio0).
atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e02b ' to make it known.
atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0xab on isa0060/serio0).
atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e02b ' to make it known.

Both f2 and f3 report the same e02b keycode.

This feature worked just fine in 12.04 LTS. Boot flags make no difference, some make it worse (as in brightness stops responding even to software hacks, e.g. custom mappings to changing brigthness via /proc). Brightness can be adjusted using 3rd party and/or command line hacks but are generally less responsive (it takes up to a second for the new brightness to register). This is on HP dm1z with AMD APU 63xx. Any ideas/reports as to what kernel compile flags are necessary and/or patches to make these work? Curiously volume and other keys work just fine.

The laptop has AMD APU 63xx series and I tried all recent fglrx drivers, including latest 15.7 and as old as 14.9 with no change to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that this is an acpi_osi quirk. For the HP dm1z (4xxx series with AMD E-450, a.k.a. Radeon HD63xx APU series) with fglrx driver, I had to add the following to my kernel boot options:

```
acpi_osi="!Windows 2012"
```

If you are adding this to the /etc/default/grub options, you will need to prepend quotes with backslashes like so:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="thermal.off=1 acpi_osi=\"!Windows 2012\""
```

Trying to use acpi_osi=Linux (with or without quotes) did not fix the problem (likely because acpi disables a number of options as soon as it detects Linux, so with the aforesaid option we spoof acpi to believe we are pre-Windows8 OS), while leaving acpi_osi= as an empty option made laptop fail to boot.